# Как убрать класс <br/> из вывода beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь спарсить сайт. Использую библиотеку beaitufulsoup4.Внутри тега span необходимо получить все теги b с их содержимым, кроме тега br. Если использовать метод .text убирается текст после тега br. Как это можно осуществить?

Разметка сайта:

[image: Разметка сайта]

Мой код:

```
def get_data():
    page = requests.get("https://www.forbes.ru/milliardery/487053-10-bogatejsih-ludej-mira-2023-rejting-forbes")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
    all_person = soup.find_all('figcaption', class_='EXdHT')
    for person in all_person:
        name = person.find('h2', class_='jYzxi').text
        about_person = person.find('div', class_='CFaZ3').find('p').find('span')
        print(about_person)

get_data()
```

Вывод терминала:
[image: Вывод терминала]

Comment: Вам нужно просто убрать БР-шки? Или текст внутри них?

Comment: Только БР - шки

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text.replace('<br>', ''), "lxml")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хоть ответ уже и дали и приняли, я все же оставлю здесь "правильный" вариант:

```
def get_data():
    page = requests.get("https://www.forbes.ru/milliardery/487053-10-bogatejsih-ludej-mira-2023-rejting-forbes")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
    all_person = soup.find_all('figcaption', class_='EXdHT')
    for person in all_person:
        name = person.find('h2', class_='jYzxi').text
        about_person = person.find('div', class_='CFaZ3').find('p').find('span')
        for s in about_person.select('br'):
            s.extract()
        print(about_person)
```

Вывод:

```
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$211,8 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>LVMH<b>Возраст: </b>74<b>Страна: </b>Франция</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$180 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>Tesla, SpaceX<b>Возраст: </b>51<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
<span><b>Состояние:</b> $114 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>Amazon.com<b>Возраст:</b> 59<b>Страна:</b> США</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$107 млрд<b>Источник состояния:</b> Oracle<b>Возраст:</b> 78<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$106 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>Berkshire Hathaway<b>Возраст: </b>92<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
<span><b>Состояние:</b> $104 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>Microsoft, инвестиции<b>Возраст:</b> 67<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
<span><b>Состояние:</b> $94,5 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>Bloomberg L.P.<b>Возраст:</b> 81<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$93 млрд<b>Источник состояния:</b> телекоммуникации<b>Возраст: </b>83<b>Страна: </b>Мексика</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$83,4 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>инвестиции<b>Возраст: </b>65<b>Страна: </b>Индия</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$80,7 млрд<b>Изменение за год: </b>минус $936 млн<b>Источник состояния: </b>Microsoft<b>Возраст: </b>67<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
```

Comment: Да, вот это хороший, "настоящий" метод)) Я использовал простую стандартную функцию

Answer (score 1):

Ой, делов-то:)
Используйте стандартный метод `.replace('<br/>', '')`. Для этого переводим переменную `about_person` из типа `bs4.element.Tag` в `str`.

---

То есть вот ваш код:

```
def get_data():
    page = requests.get("https://www.forbes.ru/milliardery/487053-10-bogatejsih-ludej-mira-2023-rejting-forbes")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
    all_person = soup.find_all('figcaption', class_='EXdHT')
    for person in all_person:
        name = person.find('h2', class_='jYzxi').text
        about_person = person.find('div', class_='CFaZ3').find('p').find('span')
        about_person=str(about_person).replace('<br/>', '')
        print(about_person)

get_data()
```

Вывод:

```
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$211,8 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>LVMH<b>Возраст: </b>74<b>Страна: </b>Франция</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$180 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>Tesla, SpaceX<b>Возраст: </b>51<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
<span><b>Состояние:</b> $114 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>Amazon.com<b>Возраст:</b> 59<b>Страна:</b> США</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$107 млрд<b>Источник состояния:</b> Oracle<b>Возраст:</b> 78<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$106 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>Berkshire Hathaway<b>Возраст: </b>92<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
<span><b>Состояние:</b> $104 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>Microsoft, инвестиции<b>Возраст:</b> 67<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
<span><b>Состояние:</b> $94,5 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>Bloomberg L.P.<b>Возраст:</b> 81<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$93 млрд<b>Источник состояния:</b> телекоммуникации<b>Возраст: </b>83<b>Страна: </b>Мексика</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$83,4 млрд<b>Источник состояния: </b>инвестиции<b>Возраст: </b>65<b>Страна: </b>Индия</span>
<span><b>Состояние: </b>$80,7 млрд<b>Изменение за год: </b>минус $936 млн<b>Источник состояния: </b>Microsoft<b>Возраст: </b>67<b>Страна: </b>США</span>
```

---

Далее с данными `str` делайте что хотите - добавляйте в массив, соединяйте в одну переменную...